# "Malware detected on my website", a message from Bing webmaster tools for a URL of a deleted page of my blogger website. What shall I do?

Tags: blogger, bing, malware, bing-webmaster-tools

Today I received a message in the dashboard of Bing webmaster tools notifying me "Malware detected on my website" for the URL of a page which I deleted a month ago. Though I didn't notify it to the Bing with the content removal tool. So, what shall I do now? Please Help.

And in the details of the message. 
Type: Malware reference found on the page. 
Additional Details: Malware Network Reference.

Comment: I think this might be a bug in Bing Webmasters. i received the same email. Checked the posts & pages it listed with various Malware sites & none were flagged as infected.

Comment: Have you checked the domain status in Search Console?

Comment: There is no such warning in the console. But only the message Malware detected on my domain.

Answer (score 1):

As per Bing documentation:

> **Malware Network Reference** - Reference to known malware distribution
>   network detected. This could be via inclusion of an iframe or frame
>   tag, an embedded object, or a script tag.

Also important this part:

> There are two over-arching issue categories:
>
> 1. Malware found on the page: the issue is immediately present on the page with the reported URL
> 2. **Malware reference** found on the page: the issue is present on a resource linked or associated with the page

What I'd advise you to do is:

1. Check your whole site for possibly being hacked: Review source code
   to see if it has been tampered with, check your site (html, scripts, etc) using different user agents (how Bing sees it, Googlebot, different browsers, etc.).
2. If the page is deleted as you say, force a deletion on Bing console.
3. Ask for a malware reevaluation

Source:
https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/malware-re-evaluation-e6982183

Comment: The warning is resolved automatically.